# Mac Chrome only quits with command+option+q

Tags: google-chrome, keybindings

All of a sudden Chrome on my Catalina imac requires command+option+q to quit. "Warn before quitting" is unchecked. Holding command+q does nothing. command+q works in all other apps.

I have a laptop with the same OS and command+q works fine on Chrome. Is there another setting somewhere I'm missing?

OS is 10.15.6 Chrome is Mac Version 85.0.4183.102

Tx

Comment: Did you try reinstall Chrome?

Comment: In the menu bar, under Chrome > Warn Before Quitting (⌘Q) is there a checkmark next to it? If so, deselect it and try quitting with a normal ⌘Q.

Comment: @agarza The OP states clearly that "Warn before quitting" is unchecked.

Comment: Doh! I have no idea how I missed that. My apologies.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and re-installing, no go. I've checked and reset all key commands under the Sys Prefs too.

Comment: bump, no answer to this yet? I'm on Big Sur now 11.4 with Chrome Version 91.0.4472.106 (Official Build) (x86_64)